# Unknown bash command causing PC to freeze

Tags: linux, bash, debian, windows-subsystem-for-linux

So I've just installed debian in the form of Windows Subsystem for Linux and I was just playing around with it. I asked on some forum (4chan) about some fun random bash scripts/commands, and someone posted this:

**Please do not execute this!!**

:(){ :|:& }; :

What exactly does this do? I entered it in and my PC just froze up and had to do a reboot. I tried putting it in a search engine but nothing showed up.

Comment: It's a fork bomb; see [the nixCraft article: "Understanding Bash fork() Bomb ~ :(){ :|:& };:"](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/understanding-bash-fork-bomb/)

Comment: I don't know if this needs saying, but don't run any more fun random bash commands from 4chan